# Linux Virtual Hosts - Can I Setup Dynamic Naming?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I don't know how else to word this question. To clarify:

I currently setup vhosts on my machine so I can access this folder:

/home/apps/somework/public

by using:

local.somework.com

I have to setup a vhost for each one. Is there a way to tell apache where to look for these routes? To automatically rewrite, so to speak?

I may even use different folders for different things and I'd love to be able to go:

local.websites.simple.com

/home/websites/simple/public

Ideas? Possible?

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, you're looking to automatically serve new vhosts based on a directory name. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: that's exactly what I'm asking. This is in a local development environment.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

http://web-magician.blogspot.com/2007/07/dynamic-virtual-host-with-apache.html